# Elastic Search Aggregation query parameter to visualize bar chart

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation, query-string, elasticsearch-api

So I want to create a bar chart to display all the "name" fields of all the animal groups in the x-axis and its total "value" field in the y-axis(or vice-versa) from now to 6 months before.
What will the query parameter be for this?
Couldn't seem to visualize this in Kibana either: the "AnimalGroup" field wasn't available to select.

**The data structure is as follows:**

```
"hits" : [
      {
       "_source" : {
           "AnimalGroup":[
             {
                "value": 12,
                "name": cat
              },
             {
                "value": 13,
                "name": dog
             },
           ],
      {
        "_source":{
          "AnimalGroup":[
             {
                "value": 12,
                "name": fish
              },
             {
                "value": 50,
                "name": dog
             },
           ]
        } 
     }
]
```

**Mapping:**

```
"mappings" : {
      "dynamic_templates" : [ ],
      "properties" : {
        "AnimalGroup" : {
          "properties" : {
            "value" : {
              "type" : "long"
            },
            "name" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
}
```

EDIT: Added the mapping of the data.

Comment: Can you please add index mapping ? you can get using `GET index_name/_mapping` api.

Comment: @Sagar Patel okk done!

Comment: Please check below my answer. Added setps for Vertical bar chart.

Answer (score 0):

You need to select `sum` aggregation on `Y-axis` and select `AnimalGroup.value` as field.

You need to select `Terms` aggregation on `X-axis` and select `AnimalGroup.name.keyword` as field.

**Y-axis**

[image]

**X-axis**

[image]

**Graph**

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response man. Um I did try that out but like the "AnimalGroup.value" nor the "AnimalGroup.name.keyword" field is not available in the list of fields in Kibana. Is this an issue in the dataset itself?

Comment: did you selected correct index pattern ? did you created index pattern first then index data ? if yes then go to `Stack Management => Index Pattern  => your_index_pattern` and click on refresh icon and then check.